# É possível colocar #ancora href em imagem?

Tags: ancora

A maioria das ancoras são colocadas em algum local do texto, gostaria de saber se é possível colocar a #ancora href em uma imagem?

Comment: De um exemplo do que quer fazer.

Comment: Neste artigo https://bomdemarca.com.br/marca/adorama/ eu utilizo um shortcode para inserir o formulário de reviews e logo acima desse formulario tem uma mini imagem, quero inserir a ancora nela para que quando o usuário clicar no link seja levado diretamente para esse formulário.

Comment: Qual mini imagem? Qual link?

Comment: @dvd Essa é imagem https://bomdemarca.com.br/wp-content/plugins/reviewBuilderPro/assets/page/img/comment-loader.gif na qual gostaria de iserir a ancora, o link vai ser colocado no início da página e quando o usuário clicar deve ser levado direto para o formulário que está abaixo dessa imagem. Para ver essa imagem é preciso ver verificar o código fonte da página https://bomdemarca.com.br/marca/adorama/ .

Comment: PQ não coloca essas informações na pergunta?

Comment: Vc já testou se funciona?